# Dividing items in two columns

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have to create an exercise list with (say) 5 items:

(a)

(b)

(c)

(d)

(e)

But I would like it to "save paper space" presenting it like that:

(a)           [space]             (d)

(b)           [space]             (e)

(c)

where [space] is of course automatically controlled by Latex.

How should I do that, please?   (Sometimes there are - say - 20 items, not 5)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems a job for the `multicol` package.

Comment: Is there any text after the labels, or is just a list of labels? In the first case, you might take  a look at the `tasks` package, which produces a horizontal first, then vertical  enumeration (i.e. in the order `(a) [space] (b)`, then  `(c) [space] (d)`, then `(e)`.

Comment: There are formulas (integrals to be calculated) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved with the *multicol* package. Here would be your document:

```
\documentclass{report}

 \usepackage{multicol} % package to use the multicols environment.
 \usepackage{enumitem} % package to modify to enumerate environment to produce (a), (b), ... items.
 \begin{document}

 \begin{multicols}{2} %2 refers to the numbers of columns.
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
   \item exercise 1
   \item exercise 2
   \item exercise 3
   \item exercise 4
   \item exercise 5
   \item exercise 6
   \item exercise 7
   \item exercise 8
   \item exercise 9
   \item exercise 10
   \item exercise 11
   \item exercise 12
   \item exercise 13
   \item exercise 14
   \item exercise 15
   \item exercise 16
   \item exercise 17
   \item exercise 18
   \item exercise 19
   \item exercise 20
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Here is the output: [image: Output of the above .tex file]

I hope this answers your question.

Best,

Krak

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what can be done with`tasks` which uses another numbering scheme:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{tasks}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\everymath{\displaystyle}}
\settasks{counter-format=(tsk[a]),label-width=1.5em}
\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Solve the following equations:
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\int \frac{x-2}{x+2}\dd x$
 \task A very very long equation $2$, spreading over two lines.
 \task* Equation $3$ is a still longer equation, spreading over two columns
\task Equation $4$ is another equation
 \task Equation $5$
 \task Equation $6$
\end{tasks}

\end{document} %
```

[image]

Comment: The items a not numbered as requested by fskilnik.

Comment: @pzorba75: I know – I mentioned ‘another numbering scheme’. It's only a suggestion, but personally, I think it's better in this situation ( usuallywe read  horizontally, not vertically).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the second alternative, Bernand. it´s great (for us all) to have both options stated in the same place, I believe!